# Ghost vertex haunting my model

Tags: mesh, distort

I'm new to Blender, and have made so many mistakes, but have learned so many new things as well. One area I'm struggling to find help on is this; there's one vertex that's causing me issues [image]. When my model is upright, there's no issue. But when he goes down to far, it begins distorting my mesh [image].

I cannot click on it. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?[image]

Comment: hello please share your file https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ySzOSYkq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ySzOSYkq/)

Comment: Added another pic. Looks like it's connect to the armature.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex is not correctly assigned, what you can do is copy the same weight as the adjacent vertex: Select your bad vertex, remove it from all groups:

[image]

Then keep it selected, shift select the adjacent one, open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights* and click on all the *Paste Weight to Selected* buttons so that your vertex inherit the same vertex groups:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't seem to work. I also completed deleted those vertices and rebuilt them. Same issue. It seems a piece of the armature isn't moving with the rest of the model. Again, I'm new. So maybe I just don't understand what you're seeing.

Comment: could you share your file but with the pose that allows to show the vertex you're talking about? If you're talking about the vertex on its back, what I did fixed the problem, I'm not sure why you're failing

Comment: Yep. Here you go. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=3j8Gvgor" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3j8Gvgor/)

Comment: What's weird, if I move it in Object View, I don't have this problem.

Comment: So yes I was talking about the same vertex and if you follow the steps it fixes your problem, see my edit

Comment: I was choosing the wrong vertices. Thanks for clearing it you. You rock! I really appreciate you!!!